# Clicking on button shows the next div

Tags: javascript

I cannot make a function that would let me go to the next div.

I've tried some thing but I just couldn't make it work for some reason

```html
<button type="button" name="button" onclick="arrowLeft()" id="arrowLeft">Prev</button>
<button type="button" name="button" onclick="arrowRight()" id="arrowRight">Next</button>

<div class="monsterTabs" id="monsterTabs">
  <div class="monsterType" id="monsterSlime" style="display:block;">
    Slime
  </div>
  <div class="monsterType" id="monsterZombie" style="display:none;">
    Zombie
  </div>
  <div class="monsterType" id="monsterSkeleton" style="display:none;">
    Skeleton
  </div>
  <div class="monsterType" id="monsterWolf" style="display:none;">
    Wolf
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gfx873ve/3

I want to know the best way to make it so i can go through the divs without a problem.

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Comment: You have `arrowRight()` and `arrowLeft()` in your `onclick` attributes, but where are those functions defined? You should add them to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a collection of all monsters by using `document.getElementsByClassName('monsterType');` then update the display property of each one when you call the `arrowLeft` and `arrowRight` functions.

I used a `monsterId` variable to control which monster is currently displayed.  Each element in `monsters` has its display property set to `none` unless it is the `monsterId`-th element in the list.

The `monsterId = (monsterId + monsters.length) % monsters.length;` line uses the modulus (%) operator to make sure the monsterId is always between 0 and monsters.length - 1.

```js
let monsters = document.getElementsByClassName('monsterType');
let monsterId = 0;

function arrowLeft() {
  updateMonster(-1);
}

function arrowRight() {
 updateMonster(1);
}

function updateMonster(direction) {  
  monsterId += direction;
  monsterId = (monsterId + monsters.length) % monsters.length;
  
  for(var i = 0; i < monsters.length; i++){
    monsters[i].style.display = i === monsterId ? 'block' : 'none';
  }  
}
```

```html
<button type="button" name="button" onclick="arrowLeft()" id="arrowLeft">Prev</button>
<button type="button" name="button" onclick="arrowRight()" id="arrowRight">Next</button>


<div class="monsterTabs" id="monsterTabs">
  <div class="monsterType" id="monsterSlime" style="display:block;">
    Slime
  </div>
  <div class="monsterType" id="monsterZombie" style="display:none;">
    Zombie
  </div>
  <div class="monsterType" id="monsterSkeleton" style="display:none;">
    Skeleton
  </div>
  <div class="monsterType" id="monsterWolf" style="display:none;">
    Wolf
  </div>
</div>
```